# How to free space in a directory or folder

Tags: partitioning, 15.04, lightdm, disk-usage

I often have problems with partitions being full, for example

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /dev
tmpfs 385M 46M 340M 12% /run
/dev/sda5 94G 5.7G 84G 7% /
tmpfs 1.9G 4.2M 1.9G 1% /dev/shm
tmpfs 5.0M 4.0K 5.0M 1% /run/lock
tmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8 94G 94G 0 100% /var          # I want to free space here
/dev/sda6 4.6G 105M 4.3G 3% /boot
/dev/sda9 708G 1.4G 671G 1% /home
/dev/sda7 9.3G 24M 8.8G 1% /tmp
cgmfs 100K 0 100K 0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs 385M 72K 385M 1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs 385M 976K 384M 1% /run/user/119
```

var which is full. It already uses 100% space. I noticed that the file `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` is almost 93GB. I deleted this file without terminal. And that directory contains `lightdm.log.old` file also and after delete `lightdm.log` I rename `lightdm.log.old to lightdm.log`. But space is not free yet. In this situation how do I free space in `/dev/sda8 94G 94G 0 100% /var`?

Comment: You should restart `lightdm`. If a file is kept open by a running program, then Linux keeps the contents and marks the file as deleted until the program lets go.

Comment: How do I restart 'lightdm'? Or restart my system? @muru

Comment: Rebooting would work too. Restart lightdm: `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`. It was pointless to rename `lightdm.log.old` - you can just delete that old log too. If you are using 15.04, please upgrade to a supported release like 16.04, as 15.04 has been unsupported for nearly two years.

Comment: questions: why do you have a separate /var/? Using it as a server? If so... check the files in /var/log/ for logs that are big (or lots of compressed files) and check why and solve that problem. Using mysql? If so check size of the database. And this: "/dev/sda5 94G 5.7G 84G 7% /"  seems a waste of space when you have a separate /var/